# App Engine Connected Android Project - Could not find ...RequestFactorySource

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I'm unable to run even the default App Engine connected Android app, since updating my SDK.  I've gone as far as deleting eclipse and all of my libraries and reinstalling them with no success.  I've followed Google's tutorial to the letter and verified the validation tool is in my build path.  This is the error I'm getting (and yes requestfactory-client.jar is in my library).

```
dalvikvm(375): Could not find method com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.RequestFactorySource.create, referenced from method com.Util.getRequestFactory
dalvikvm(375): VFY: unable to resolve static method 84: Lcom/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/vm/RequestFactorySource;.create (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/RequestFactory;
```

I'm completely lost at this point and about to pull some hair out, please help.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it's an issue with the new ADT 17 and how it handles library projects. This post is a good explanation on how to fix it:

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

I, too, was going crazy on this.  Hope this helps.

The validation step can be important too (like you did):

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation